# Photos are not showing up when using No-IP ddns and linux apache

Tags: html, linux, apache, dns, dhcp

I don't have a static IP address so a person recommended that I use no-ip.com

I did and now my website is accessible from external internet yay

The problem now is that my photos aren't showing, I thought this would have been a simple issue

I'm not sure if I have to do something with Virtual Host or...

My domain name is greenace92.ddns.net

I can access my index.html file, that shows up fine but the photos aren't showing

On my httpd.conf file I have

```
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"
```

The html files are in htdocs under apache2

So, on virtual host that httpd-vhosts.conf file I have the following

```
ServerAdmin "jacobcun@ricekidengineer.com"
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/"
ServerName "www.greenace92.ddns.net"
```

*ricekidengineer.com is my other domain with email configured

I didn't change the error logs from stuck "dummy" stuff

So on my html file for image href's I have

```
http://www.greenace92.ddns.net/htdocs/images/normalbus-icon-on.png
```

I assume that www.greenace92.ddns.net is /usr/local/apache2

So I'm just continuing the directory location

Is that correct? What is wrong?

Yeah I don't understand, I even tried three different directories for a few photos, trying directly in apache2, then htdocs, then the images folder

What am I not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to decide what your want as the domain for your site:

- **`www`**.`greenace92.ddns.net` is not setup for your web site
- `greenace92.ddns.net` is the domain setup for your web site.

You either have to

- configure no-ip.com to point to the domain **`www`**.`greenace92.ddns.net`

(or)

- change your apache ServerName directive to

  ```
  ServerName "greenace92.ddns.net"
  ```

  and change the image URLs in your HTML pages from something like

  ```
    http://www.greenace92.ddns.net/htdocs/images/normalbus-icon-on.png
  ```

  to

  ```
    http://greenace92.ddns.net/images/normalbus-icon-on.png
  ```

**Note:** With your current configuration, the 2nd URL mentioned above should already work (It worked when I tested!).

Comment: I tried to change the host, wouldn't allow me www preceding isn't accepted. I thought www was an auto-complete thing for web not the world wide web acronym but I thought was filled in automatically if you didn't explicitly type it.

Comment: Change the image URLs then (as mentioned above)

Comment: Yeah still not working I don't understand. I am using a Virgin Mobile 3G Android phone (old) to access the site externally. Not sure if accessing it from my own wifi works as external access or if it goes local

Comment: I made an edit just few seconds ago...check this again: http://greenace92.ddns.net/images/normalbus-icon-on.png

Comment: Check as in, when I clicked on it, it downloaded? The file did download, it doesn't show up on my external web testing device eg. old android phone

Comment: Ha, I was like where is the tick mark. Hey thanks again very much, this means a lot to me, it's progress.